# Как проще всего разработать приложение-ссылку на рабочем столе ipad?

Tags: ios, ipad

Вот такой вопрос, нужно на рабочем столе ipad (где обычные приложения) разместить иконки при нажатии на которую происходит открытие браузера chrome по определенной ссылке.
Вопрос как это проще всего сделать. Можно ли так будет сделать чтобы такое приложение было внутри app store? Либо можно ли его будет установить локально без app store?

Comment: Нужен именно Chrome или сойдёт и Safari?

Comment: chrome и чтобы можно было иконку свою задать

Answer (score 2):

Максимально простой вариант, не требующий никаких приложений (а приложение, открывающее одну ссылку и только в Chrome, точно не пропустят для публикации) – использовать `Shortcuts`.

Заходите в программу, ищете Chrome:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Выбираете "Открывать URL в Chrome" и создаёте команду:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Затем нажимаете кнопку с 3 точками и кастомизируете как понравится, а затем добавить на экран "Домой":

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И URL открывается в Chrome. Командами можно делиться через меню поделиться:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]